# Virtualenv failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.7'

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I am currently running python3.8, and when I run

```
python3 -m virtualenv --python=python3.7 $HOME/venv_test
```

I get:

`RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.7'`

I do have python3.7 installed:

`python3.7 --version Python 3.7.13`

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Could you not do `python3.7 -m virtualenv $HOME/venv_test`?

Comment: `python3.7 -m virtualenv $HOME/venv_test` results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pathlib'`

Comment: What happens if you use the absolute path, e.g., `$ python3 -m virtualenv --python=/bin/python3.7 $HOME/venv`

Comment: How did you install virtual env module on your system?

Answer (score 0):

You should really give more details to how you installed python, and where from. The error message you are receiving is because `virutalenv` module cannot find the python3.7 executable.

1. python3.7 is not in PATH ( you can try by supplying it the absolute path to python3.7, something like --python=/usr/bin/python3.7 on linux )
2. Your python3.8 and python3.7 do not run in the same environment

No. 2. can happen if you are mixing WSL and Windows python installation for example, running virtualenv from a script, etc. Make sure you are not mixing environments, if both py versions are installed within the same environment No 1. will work.